# Clicking on specific ion-item button triggers the other buttons

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Lets suppose there are 3 elements in the array of `names`.
So, the below html will display 3 items with click button attached to every item.

**.html**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let name of names">

   <p>{{name.username}}</p>

   <button ion-button [someAttribute]="isLoad" (click)="clickTest(name.id)">
      Click
   </button>

</ion-item>
```

**.ts**

```
async clickTest(id) {

     isLoad = true;
    // await server side call
    isLoad = false;
}
```

**Requirement** : I only want the particular button change with `isLoad = true`, and not all the buttons. 
**Problem** : When clicking on `Click` button, the other buttons also gets changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is something related to how Javascript handle events (Event Bubbling).

In short you can do this:

Passing the event and invoke stopPropagation method, like this.

In **.html**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let name of names">

   <p>{{name.username}}</p>

   <button ion-button [someAttribute]="isLoad" (click)="clickTest($event, name.id)">
      Click
   </button>

</ion-item>
```

**.ts**

```
async clickTest(event:any, id) {
     event.stopPropagation();

     isLoad = true;
    // await server side call
    isLoad = false;
}
```

or, invoke such method in template:

In **.html**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let name of names">

   <p>{{name.username}}</p>

   <button ion-button [someAttribute]="isLoad" (click)="clickTest(name.id), $event.stopPropagation()">
      Click
   </button>

</ion-item>
```